# Angularjs: how to model two outputs from same array with each other

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement where i am using an array to get the values and linking them with checkbox, but i need to model the output of array such a way that upon the checked status of first output or checkbox all other should be enabled. but its not working.
below is the link of code, hope you would understand better once you go through the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/7mKtF/124/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <span class="control-label1" ng-repeat="rows in myData" ng-show="$first"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="disablelist">{{rows.name}}</span>
               <span class="control-label" ng-repeat="row in myData" ng-show="!$first"><input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="!disablelist" ng-checked="disablelist && 0">{{row.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and controller is

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.myData = [{name: "Sitemap"},
                     {name: "View"},
                     {name: "Edit"},
                     {name: "Delete"},
                     {name: "Rename"}];  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using using the model as the property of an object.

For example, instead of disablelist declare it in your controller: 
`$scope.myObj ={};  $scope.myObj.disablelist=false;`  
And update it in your interface everywhere disablelist is mentioned by replacing it with: myObj.disablelist.

Read more about this so called anti-pattern here (it's number 1 - Not having a dot in your ng-model): 
http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/

In greater detail the JavaScript Prototypal Inheritance:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes
Edit:

---

I have upated your jsfiddle first in order to work added a small correction then as i described.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer it really improved my knowledge on scope.
However the problem is i have number of section where i need functionality like this so declaring separate object for all of them would not be feasible. anyhow i will work on this and will update here. 
Thanks again :)

Comment: You can use a single object and simply add to it as you need. I am sure whichever your case is with any number of sections you can make something generic to keep your code dry. Surely you can write some directive for this.